# Lock screen stuck in landscape mode on Galaxy Tab 10.1

Tags: lock-screens

I rooted and upgraded my Galaxy Tab 10.1 to Jelly Bean 4.1.2.

One mild annoyance is that the pattern lock screen is stuck in landscape mode. I can't find any option to rotate it to portrait mode.

How can I stop the pattern lock screen from being always in landscape?

If possible, can I force the pattern lock screen to always be in portrait mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded to Android 5.0, and now this issue has been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the fact that the lockscreen recognises that the device is a tablet, and therefore makes it stay in landscape mode.

There is an easy way to counteract this, however it does require the use of a third party application called [set orientation](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.eyesfree.setorientation), which allows you to force apps into any orientation you wish.

Just open up the app, and set the drop down to 'Automatic'. The screen will then rotate when you rotate the device.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'm not sure that I believe this is just default for all tablets, though. I've had different versions of Android before this and all have been able to show the lock screen in portrait mode.